# Is it possible to convert local currency to USD by depositing the money at ATM using an American bank account?

Tags: foreign-exchange, atm

Let's say I go to Russia. I can get rubles from Moscow's Citi Bank's ATM from my Wells Fargo account at the current exchange rate. There's a fee for each transaction, but it is very little. If you exchange USD for rubles at airport, the rate is very unfair due to the instability of the rate. Then, is it possible to deposit rubles at the same ATM to get USD in my account at the same rate?

Comment: You want to deposit cash (rubles) into a Citi Bank branded ATM in Moscow, Russia and expect CitiBank to exchange it for US dollars and credit the sum to your _Wells Fargo_ account somewhere in the US?  Are you that you can even deposit US dollars into a Citibank ATM in Moscow, Idaho and have that money credited into your Wells Fargo account in the US? let alone rubles into a Russian CitiBank ATM for conversion into US dollars into your Wells Fargo account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, is it possible to deposit rubles at the same ATM to get USD in my account at the same rate?

No this is not possible. Generally deposits into accounts outside country and not offered.